# Optimize writing to CSV in Go

Tags: go

The following snippet validates a phone number and write the details to CSV.

```
func Parse(phone Input, output *PhoneNumber) error {
    var n PhoneNumber
    num, _ := phonenumbers.Parse(phone.Number, phone.Prefix)
    n.PhoneNumber = phonenumbers.Format(num, phonenumbers.E164)
    n.CountryCode = num.GetCountryCode()
    n.PhoneType = phonenumbers.GetNumberType(num)
    n.NetworkName, _ = phonenumbers.GetCarrierForNumber(num, "EN")
    n.Region = phonenumbers.GetRegionCodeForNumber(num)
    *output = n
    return nil
}

func createFile(path string) {
    // detect if file exists
    var _, err = os.Stat(path)

    // create file if not exists
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        var file, err = os.Create(path)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        defer file.Close()
    }
}

func worker(ctx context.Context, dst chan string, src chan []string) {
    for {
        select {
        case dataArray, ok := <-src: // you must check for readable state of the channel.
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            go processNumber(dataArray[0])
        case <-ctx.Done(): // if the context is cancelled, quit.
            return
        }
    }
}

func processNumber(number string) {
    num, e := phonenumbers.Parse(number, "")
    if e != nil {
        return
    }
    region := phonenumbers.GetRegionCodeForNumber(num)
    carrier, _ := phonenumbers.GetCarrierForNumber(num, "EN")
    path := "sample_all.csv"
    createFile(path)
    var csvFile, _ = os.OpenFile(path, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, os.ModeAppend)
    csvwriter := csv.NewWriter(csvFile)
    _ = csvwriter.Write([]string{phonenumbers.Format(num, phonenumbers.E164), fmt.Sprintf("%v", num.GetCountryCode()), fmt.Sprintf("%v", phonenumbers.GetNumberType(num)), carrier, region})

    defer csvFile.Close()

    csvwriter.Flush()
}

func ParseFile(phone Input, output *PhoneNumber) error {

    // create a context
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()
    // that cancels at ctrl+C
    go onSignal(os.Interrupt, cancel)

    numberOfWorkers := 2

    start := time.Now()

    csvfile, err := os.Open(phone.File)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer csvfile.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(csvfile)

    // create the pair of input/output channels for the controller=>workers com.
    src := make(chan []string)
    out := make(chan string)

    // use a waitgroup to manage synchronization
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // declare the workers
    for i := 0; i < numberOfWorkers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            worker(ctx, out, src)
        }()
    }

    // read the csv and write it to src
    go func() {
        for {
            record, err := reader.Read()
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            } else if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            src <- record // you might select on ctx.Done().
        }
        close(src) // close src to signal workers that no more job are incoming.
    }()

    // wait for worker group to finish and close out
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()  // wait for writers to quit.
        close(out) // when you close(out) it breaks the below loop.
    }()

    // drain the output
    for res := range out {
        fmt.Println(res)
    }

    fmt.Printf("\n%2fs", time.Since(start).Seconds())
    return nil
}
```

In processNumber function, if I skip writing to CSV, the process of verifying number completes 6 seconds but writing one record at a time on CSV stretch the time consumption to 15s.

How can I optimize the code?
Can I chunk the records and write them in chunks instead of writing one row at a time?

Comment: Open-write-close will take a lot of time. Open the file once, write all rows, then close. You need to restructure your program so there is only one writer goroutine that reads the rows from a channel and writes to the file.

Comment: And buffer your file writes.

Comment: Any example snippet would be helpful?

Comment: There's no point in creating a worker pool when the worker pool creates a new goroutine for each task.  The program does not guarantee that `processNumber` goroutines complete before the program exits.  Address both of these issues by changing `go processNumber(dataArray[0])` to `processNumber(dataArray[0])`.

Comment: oh yeah! @CeriseLimón, I removed `go` from the that given line... It seems to be little bit of time consuming but the entire data is written in file.

Comment: Anyone has idea why the question is downvoted? I need to understand why the question is downvoted and prepare myself for future questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do work directly in worker goroutine instead of firing off goroutine per task.

Open file output file once.  Flush output file once.

```
func worker(ctx context.Context, dst chan []string, src chan []string) {
    for {
        select {
        case dataArray, ok := <-src: // you must check for readable state of the channel.
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            dst <- processNumber(dataArray[0])
        case <-ctx.Done(): // if the context is cancelled, quit.
            return
        }
    }
}

func processNumber(number string) []string {
    num, e := phonenumbers.Parse(number, "")
    if e != nil {
        return
    }
    region := phonenumbers.GetRegionCodeForNumber(num)
    carrier, _ := phonenumbers.GetCarrierForNumber(num, "EN")
    return []string{phonenumbers.Format(num, phonenumbers.E164), fmt.Sprintf("%v", num.GetCountryCode()), fmt.Sprintf("%v", phonenumbers.GetNumberType(num)), carrier, region}
}

func ParseFile(phone Input, output *PhoneNumber) error {

    // create a context
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()
    // that cancels at ctrl+C
    go onSignal(os.Interrupt, cancel)

    numberOfWorkers := 2

    start := time.Now()

    csvfile, err := os.Open(phone.File)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer csvfile.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(csvfile)

    // create the pair of input/output channels for the controller=>workers com.
    src := make(chan []string)
    out := make(chan string)

    // use a waitgroup to manage synchronization
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // declare the workers
    for i := 0; i < numberOfWorkers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            worker(ctx, out, src)
        }()
    }

    // read the csv and write it to src
    go func() {
        for {
            record, err := reader.Read()
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            } else if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            src <- record // you might select on ctx.Done().
        }
        close(src) // close src to signal workers that no more job are incoming.
    }()

    // wait for worker group to finish and close out
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()  // wait for writers to quit.
        close(out) // when you close(out) it breaks the below loop.
    }()

    path := "sample_all.csv"

    file, err := os.Create(path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()
    csvwriter := csv.NewWriter(csvFile)

    // drain the output
    for res := range out {
        csvwriter.Write(res)
    }
    csvwriter.Flush()

    fmt.Printf("\n%2fs", time.Since(start).Seconds())
    return nil
}
```